# Return the value of a selected Qubit from Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

I have a quantum circuit and the job has been run on the "statevector" backend, which runs only 1 shot.

Therefore is there a way to return the qubit state (0 or 1) specifically when selected specifically ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you mean by "return the qubit state (0 or 1) specifically"? For example, what would you expect to be returned for the Bell state?

Answer (score 1):

The `statevector` backend returns the final state vector at the end of the circuit. If you would like to return the counts instead, the `qasm_simulator` should be used. This returns, in the result object, a dictionary which contains the results as keys and the number of times the result was seen as values. For example, for a circuit that constructs a Bell state, run 10 times, this could be `{00: 6, 11: 4}`